# Spring Boot with Handlebars: could not find helper: 'dateFormat'

Tags: spring-boot, handlebars.java

I'm trying to get the handlebars dateFormat to work. At the moment I'm getting the error `com.github.jknack.handlebars.HandlebarsException: /hbs/doc/docheader.hbs:6:12: could not find helper: 'dateFormat'`

when I call `{{dateFormat doc.documentDate format="yyyy-MM-dd"}}`.

This is my relevant gradle configuration: 

`compile 'pl.allegro.tech.boot:handlebars-spring-boot-starter:0.2.14'
compile 'com.github.jknack:handlebars-helpers:4.0.6',
        'com.github.jknack:handlebars-jackson2:4.0.6',
        'com.github.jknack:handlebars-humanize:4.0.6',
        'com.github.jknack:handlebars-markdown:4.0.6'`
 
As far as I understand the string helpers should be included in handlebars-jackson2:4.0.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that the string helpers are not registered by default. The following code made it work:

```
TemplateLoader loader = new ClassPathTemplateLoader("/hbs", ".hbs");
this.handlebars = new Handlebars(loader);
StringHelpers.register(this.handlebars);
```

Comment: Where is this code placed?  In a Configuration Class or Test Class?  I am assuming this is Java code?  Thanks.